# jQuery - How to get the amount of input from the deleted row

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i delete any row of the table, the value of `<input class="fullprice">` should subtracted from the `<input id="total">`
**Now**. how can I return the value of `<input class="fullprice">` from deleted row?
*i don't know what should i say to solve the problem of `add some more details`, tell me in comments*

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
                    if (retResult) {
                        console.log($('.fullprice').val());
                        $row.remove();
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Full price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[2][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 2.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][inprice]" class="price" value="17"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][count]" class="count"  value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][fullprice]" class="fullprice"  value="340"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Macaroni 700 (Gr)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="5"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="100"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 1.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="9"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="180"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="total" value="620">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three issues:

1. you are manually adding the total in the html, and this would pose if a problem in case you changed the numbers or had more inputs.
2. you are getting the value of the first element having '.fullprice' class, when you actually want to get the one relevant to the item you just deleted
3. you are not subtracting the number

I have solved these three problems with the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var totals = $('.fullprice');
    var total = 0;
    $.each(totals,function(index,fullprice){{
        console.log(fullprice.value);
        total += parseInt(fullprice.value);
    }});
    $('#total').val(total);
    $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
        if (retResult) {
            
            var num_to_remove = parseInt($row.find('.fullprice').val());
            var old_total = parseInt($('#total').val());
            var new_total = old_total - num_to_remove;
            $('#total').val(new_total);
            $row.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Full price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[2][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 2.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][inprice]" class="price" value="17"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][count]" class="count"  value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][fullprice]" class="fullprice"  value="340"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Macaroni 700 (Gr)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="5"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="100"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 1.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="9"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="180"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="total" value="">
```

please note that this code will only get the sum in the first time you run it, whereas there might be better ways to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can find the correspondent fullprice using `.find`

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
                var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
                if (retResult) {
                    console.log(row.find('.fullprice').val());
                    $row.remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

But it's a better solution to just recalc the total on deletion or update:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
                var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
                if (retResult) {
                    $row.remove();
                    calcTotal();
                }
            });
            $("table").on("keyup", ".price, .count, fullprice", function(e) {
                calcTotal();
            });

        });

        function calcTotal() {    
           var Total = 0;
           $("table").find("tr").each(function (i, el) {
              Total += parseFloat($(el).find('.fullprice').val());
           });
           $("#total").val(Total);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through `.fullprice` and get the value and sum. Try the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
        if (retResult) {
            console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('.fullprice').val());
            $row.remove();
        }

        var total = 0;  

        if( $('.fullprice').length ){
            $('.fullprice').each(function(){
                total = total + parseInt($(this).val());
            });
        }

        $('#total').val(total);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Full price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[2][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 2.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][inprice]" class="price" value="17"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][count]" class="count"  value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][fullprice]" class="fullprice"  value="340"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Macaroni 700 (Gr)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="5"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="100"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 1.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="9"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="180"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="total" value="620">
```

Answer (score -1):

I have updated the code snippet. but this is not the right way to update get the `total` value. since it's static `HTML`, I am just updating the input value after deletion of a `row`.

Ideally, you need to get all the input values and keep updating the total input value based on the change event handler for all the `input` fields.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("table").on("click", ".del-service", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
                    var $total = $('#total');
                    var retResult = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this line?");
                    if (retResult) {
                        var val = $('.fullprice').val();
                        $row.remove();
                        total.value = total.value - val;
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Full price</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[2][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 2.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][inprice]" class="price" value="17"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][count]" class="count"  value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[2][fullprice]" class="fullprice"  value="340"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Macaroni 700 (Gr)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="5"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="100"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="product[3][product_name]" class="product_name" value="Soda 1.5 (L)"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][inprice]" class="price" value="9"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][count]" class="count" value="20"></td>
            <td><input name="product[3][fullprice]" class="fullprice" value="180"></td>
            <td><a class="del-service" href="#" title="Click to remove this entry">Delete Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="total" value="620">
```

Comment: this code still has an issue, this selects the first Item in the class, you should make sure its the '.fullprice' inside the deleted row